# WebView displaying all white screen

Tags: java, android, webview

I've been experimenting with webview to make a web hosted android app and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is here, all it's doing is rendering an all white screen.

Does anyone know what could be wrong with it?

I don't want to share the link to the page it's supposed to render but it is made in React and if you go to the domain it renders the app. So I know it's not a problem with the website.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Main_Activity.java**

```
package com.example.firstapp;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);


        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
       mWebView.loadUrl("https://myprivatelink.com");
    }

}
```

**Android_Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FirstApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added Internet permission but have you allowed it on your phone?

Go to your phone settings and **allow internet permission** for this app.

Try it and give me feedback.

Comment: I'll be home later tonight and I'll let you know if that's the case but how would I make it so you don't have to do that, I don't want everyone to have to go in their settings and allow it once I publish the app to play store.

Comment: Add run time permission on your app,
You will get code for that on geeksforgeeks or any other online websites, just understand and copy the code.